# Cauchy-Riemann: am I applying the equations correctly?

Tags: derivatives, complex-numbers, partial-derivative

$$\text{Re}(z) +i\text{ Im}(z)^2$$

The problem states to apply C-R and to describe what can be concluded. However, I don't understand what I can conclude without a point $z_0$.

**My conclusion:**

$$u(x,y)=x$$
$$v(x,y)=y^2$$

Applying C-R:

$$u_x=1$$
$$v_y=2y$$
The 2 above don't match, but the 2 below do.

$$u_y=0$$
$$v_x=0$$

Am I to conclude that the function is not differentiable at any value of $z$?

Comment: Do you mean $Im(z^2)$ or $(Im(z))^2?$ Note that $Im(z^2)=2xy$ and $(Im(z))^2=y^2.$

Comment: I wrote it just like it is on the paper but if I had to pick one to specify I'd say it's the second one

Comment: Ah I made a mistake. I will edit.

Comment: So, the derivative exists if and only if $2y=1.$

Comment: So I can say that as a general case then? - There exists a derivative at any point $z_0$ on $f$ if and only if $y=1/2$

Comment: Because part of my confusion came from the problem not giving me a $z_0$

Comment: Yes. $f'(z_0)$ exists if and only if $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$ at such a point.